# Max value 2d array using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to write a programm to find a maximum value in column in a initialized 5x5 matrix, and change it to -1. I found out the way to do it, but i want to find a better solution.

Input:

```
    double array2d[5][5];
        double *ptr;
        ptr = array2d[0];
//        initializing matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                if (j % 2 != 0) {
                    array2d[i][j] = (i + 1) - 2.5;
                } else {
                    array2d[i][j] = 2 * (i + 1) + 0.5;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my solution for the first column :

```
//        Changing the matrix using pointer arithmetic

        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array2d) / sizeof(array2d[0][0])); ++i) {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                if (maxTemp <= *(ptr + i)) {
                    maxTemp = *(ptr + i);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array2d) / sizeof(array2d[0][0])); ++i) {
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                if (*(ptr + i) == maxTemp) {
                    *(ptr + i) = -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

I can repeat this code 5 times, and get the result, but i want a better solution. THX.

Comment: Why bother with pointer arithmetic?

Comment: There are actually *two* ways to use pointers and pointer arithmetic to access each element: The first is linear, and the second is nested (as in array of *arrays*). Which you you need? And *why* do you need it? What is your actual assignment/exercise? What requirements and limitations does it have? Please [edit] your question to flesh out the details and elaborate.

Comment: The task is "Using pointer arithmetic and a loop, perform operations on its elements",
the operation is "Change all maximum numbers in each column to -1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the complete program that uses pointer arithmetic. This program replaces all the maximum values in each column of the 2D array -1 as you desire.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double array2d[5][5];
    double *ptr;
    ptr = array2d[0];
    //        initializing matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            if (j % 2 != 0) {
                array2d[i][j] = (i + 1) - 2.5;
            } else {
                array2d[i][j] = 2 * (i + 1) + 0.5;
            }
        }
    }

    //these(from this point on) are the things that i have added.
    //Everything above this comment is the same as your code.  

    double (*rowBegin)[5]  = std::begin(array2d);
    double (*rowEnd)[5] = std::end(array2d);

    while(rowBegin != rowEnd)
    {
        double *colBegin = std::begin(rowBegin[0]);
        double *colEnd = std::end(rowBegin[0]);
        
        double lowestvalue = *colBegin;//for comparing elements
        //double *pointerToMaxValue = colBegin;
        
        while(colBegin!= colEnd)
        {
            if(*colBegin > lowestvalue)
            {
                lowestvalue = *colBegin;
                //pointerToMaxValue = colBegin ;
            }
            colBegin = colBegin + 1;
        }
        double *newcolBegin = std::begin(rowBegin[0]);
        double *newcolEnd = std::end(rowBegin[0]);

        while(newcolBegin!=newcolEnd)
        {
            if(*newcolBegin == lowestvalue)
            {
                *newcolBegin = -1;  
            }
            ++newcolBegin;
        }
        ++rowBegin;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program can be checked [here](https://onlinegdb.com/2jZlrYY7DN).

You can add print out all the element of the array to check whether the above program replaced all the maximum value in each column with -1.

Answer (score 0):

I have written it in java but I think u can understand. This one is for all 5 columns at the same time. You can try this:

```
int count = 0;
double max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
       if (j == 0) {
            max = array2d[j][I];
            count = 0;
       }
       if (array2d[j][i] > max) {
           count = j;
       }
   }
   array2d[count][i] = -1;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but i have to it using pointer arithmetic, as far as i know there are no pointers in Java.